# Detect an alias

Tags: applescript

Can Applescript detect if an item chosen is an alias (as in Finder alias that is a shortcut to a folder/file)?

```
set toProcess to choose folder with prompt "Select folders:" with multiple selections allowed
tell application "System Events"
    if first item in toProcess is (* alias *) then ...
end tell
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  tell application "Finder"

    set toProcess to choose folder with prompt "Select folders:" with multiple selections allowed
    set theClass to kind of (first item in toProcess)


    if theClass is "Alias" then
        display notification with title "Alias file"
    else

        display notification with title (theClass as string)
    end if

end tell
```

The `choose folder` needs to be within the finder tell block to return the result for kind in the finders context